# R Reactivity: observe running more times than expected

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny, rstudio

I am new to shiny and I need to understand a thing that's driving mad: why this code runs 3 times instead of 1

```
observe({ duplicate() })


duplicate = function() {
  for (inp in names(input)[grepl("^box", names(input))]) {
    inpCode = substr(inp, 5, nchar(inp))
    value = eval(parse(text = paste("input$", inp, sep = "")))

    if (is.na(value)){
      value = eval(parse(text = paste("input$secondbox", inpCode, sep = "")))
    }

    updateNumericInput(session, paste("thirdbox", inpCode, sep = ""), value = value)
  }
}
```

I have seen that it is related to the fact that I am reading from 3 different inputs within an observe but just updating once so it should run only once. What am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: Code is run again everytime input is updated. If you don't want that you can use `isolate()` to prevent reactivity of input. More information about [reactivity](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html) and [isolate](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/isolation.html). By providing minimal working example it would be easier to see what is happening in your case. You can also try: `shiny::runApp(display.mode="showcase")` and try to see yourself what is happening there.

Comment: I've already tried isolate but then it just run once but does not do what I want, it is some kind illogical.